# Plesk DNS Management from PHP Script?

Tags: php, dns, web-deployment, plesk, whmcs

Our company currently offers free sub-domains for redirects to our customers. These are quite a popular feature, but unfortunately every time someone requests it, our staff must login to the Plesk panel and manually create this. It is only specifying the DNS name and an IP Address for the A-Record, but it would be great to be able to automate this in our Billing System for easy creation.

As I am not overly familiar with Plesk, does anyone know how I may be able to proceed with handling the creation of an A-Record in our Plesk install via PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the commandline interface or directly using the rpc api of plesk. see http://www.parallels.com/ptn/documentation/plesk/ for more information.

for commandline this seems simple enough:
http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-unix-cli/37771.htm

Comment: This is definitely helpful, but the PHP script is going to be running remotely (on our billing system's web server) so the command line won't really work.

Comment: then use the RPC API. you can invoke shell commands also via a remote client, if you dont know :) but this would require more info on your specific environment and network topology. (how to handle security)

Comment: Yeah not to keen on how to handle remote shell commands. Our Plesk install is on Windows Server 2008 machine, but I will just look into using the RPC API as I found a PHP example on the Guide. Do you happen to know what should be passed for the SendRequest() though to create an A-Record?

Comment: sorry, cant help with that. just did a quick google search on your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowladge, Plesk is an interface for interacting and Managbe your web server settings. But It don't provide free api for doing stuff you have asked for.

You can use `RPC API` for the same. But that works using command prompt.

I am sure that would be bit complex to do.